# Factorial Calculation Fails When Input Is Higher Than 12

Tags: c#, factorial

My code does factorials for numbers, but for some reason whenever i input a number 13 or higher, it either give a wrong number or somehow gets a negative number. Any suggestions?

```
        List<int> myList = new List<int>();
        Console.WriteLine("My Job is to take the factorial of the number you give");
        Console.WriteLine("What is the number?");
        string A = Console.ReadLine();
        int C = Convert.ToInt32(A);
        int k = C;
        int B = C;
        int U = C - 1;
        Console.Write("{0} ", B);
        while (U != 0)
        {
           k *= U;
           Console.Write("* {0} ", U);
            U--;
        }
        Console.WriteLine(" = {0}", k);
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Usually you would use a recursive function for factorials, not a `while` loop.

Comment: please change your question title to a more specific and descriptive one.

Comment: I don't know the right question that needs to be asked

Comment: is there a way to store the factorial of 44 in a var or a int or long type thing (what are they called? they being var, int, long etc...)

Comment: Yes, check my answer below with the BigInteger structure. It should give you the ~57 digits as a string.

Comment: I type in BigInteger K = k but it says BigInteger could not be found

Comment: then i typed in the using statements "using System.Numerics.BigInteger;" and it said Numerics does not exist in the System namespace

Comment: oo, that's the question, Thanks Michael for the question change

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An integer is 32-bit, so max value is 2,147,483,647. 13! equates to a larger value: 6,227,020,800. You'll have to change to `long` to go any higher than 12!, which as a 64-bit number, would give you up to 9,223,372,036,854,775,807.

```
Type  Max Fact   Max Value
int   12!        6,227,020,800
long  20!        9,223,372,036,854,775,807
ulong 20!        18,446,744,073,709,551,615
```

Changing to long at least lets you go to 20! You'd have to change to a floating point to go beyond that in most systems, and even then, you'll start seeing rounding errors. Not even an unsigned long lets you get to 21!

Now, to get beyond 20!, you can use the BigInteger structure (great code project examples are out there). It has no defined upper or lower bounds, but you can run into memory/system issues if the numbers are too large for your system. According to MSDN:

> The BigInteger type is an immutable type that represents an arbitrarily large integer whose value in theory has no upper or lower bounds.

```
int factorial = 25;
BigInteger bigInt = 1;
while (factorial > 1)
    bigInt = BigInteger.Multiply(factorial--, bigInt);
var output = bigInt.ToString(); // Would give you the 26 digits
```

Resources:

- BigInteger: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger(v=vs.110).aspx
- Code Project for BigInteger: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/270413/Calculate-the-Factorial-of-an-Integer-in-Csharp
- UInt64.MaxValue (ulong): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uint64.maxvalue(v=vs.110).aspx
- Int64.MaxValue (long): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int64.maxvalue(v=vs.110).aspx
- Int32.MaxValue (int): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.maxvalue(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You're working with `integers`, which have a maximum value of `2,147,483,647` (13 numbers)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.maxvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

You need to work with a larger numeric type like say `int64`, `long`, or other in order to solve your immediate problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting integer overflow https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow
You can use

```
long k = C;
```

instead of

```
int k = C;
```

to increase overflow limit to 2^63 - 1 instead of 2^31 - 1